# terraform json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type dynamodb.AttributeValue

Tags: terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I created a dynamodb table using terraform and I added an item to it. However, I get this error "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type dynamodb.AttributeValue"

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "itemone" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_dynamodb_table.demo_dynamo_table
  ]   
  
  # required
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.demo_dynamo_table.name 
  # required
  hash_key = aws_dynamodb_table.demo_dynamo_table.hash_key 

  # key value item s attributes
  item = <<ITEM
  {
    "clientId": {"S": "001"},
    "clientAge": {"N": "11"},
    "other": {"N": "55"}
  }
  ITEM
  
}
```

my table

```
# Create_dynamoDb table
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "demo_dynamo_table" {
  name = "Client" #required uniq within region
  billing_mode = "PROVISIONED"
  hash_key = "clientId"  
  range_key = "clientAge" 

  #required 
  attribute {
    name = "clientId"
    type = "S"    
  }
  attribute {
    name = "clientAge"
    type = "N"     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was one line missing , the one of the range_key . I added the following and it works:

```
  range_key = aws_dynamodb_table.demo_dynamo_table.range_key
```

Bests,